# How to handle an error in TSQL and take control of the stored procedure

Tags: json, sql-server, t-sql, error-handling

I never have learned error trapping in T-SQL. Darn. Sometimes curl.xget in

```
SELECT @JSON = curl.xget(null, ''+@GETSTRING+'') 

INSERT INTO [pcrd].[stg1_fredSeries]
           ([SeriesCode]
           ,[realStartTime]
           ,[realEndTime]
           ,[observationDate]
           ,[observationValue]
           ,[etl_dateUpdate]
           ,[ETL_UserUpdate]
           ,fk_series_id
           ,api_url)
    SELECT 
        @SERIES_CODE AS SeriesID,
        *,
        GETDATE() AS etl_dateUpdate,
        'sp_get_fredSeriesPCTpe4' AS etl_userUpdate,
        @api_type,
        @GETSTRING
    FROM
        OPENJSON(@JSON,'$.observations')
```

Throws an error:

> Msg 6522, Level 16, State 1, Procedure pcrd.sp_get_fredSeriesPCType4, Line 72 [Batch Start Line 20]
> A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "XGET":
> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
> System.Net.WebException:
> at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadDataInternal(Uri address, WebRequest& request)
> at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadString(Uri address)
> at Curl.Get(SqlChars H, SqlChars url)

Is this just a matter or raising an error and looking for Msg 6522? This insert and the building of the `@GETSTRING` is in a cursor fetch. Can there be a BEGIN TRY in a cursor fetch? Assuming this is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are making a single call to curl.xget, you could trap the error in a try/catch.

```
fetch next from thecursor into @GETSTRING;

--better to initialize @json on each iteration
select @JSON = null; 

begin try
    SELECT @JSON = curl.xget(null, ''+@GETSTRING+'') 
end try
begin catch
    --do something with the error, log etc...or just silence it
end catch

--when error for the @json assignment, @json will be null and no insertion happens
--because openjson returns no result
INSERT INTO [pcrd].[stg1_fredSeries]
SELECT 
FROM
    OPENJSON(@JSON,'$.observations')
```